# How can I configure gateway in Remmina UI?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remmina

I`ve just installed latest versions of FreeRDP (1.2.1) and Remmina (1.2.0) and I finnaly can connect to my rdp using gateway (like this way):

```
xfreerdp /v:server /g:gateway /u:Username /p:pass +clipboard +fonts /size:1280x700 /network:broadband /bpp:3
```

But I can't find were to set gateway field in Remmina UI. I can find everything (username, server, type) except gateway and therefore Remmina can`t connect to my rdp server. Can you please help me and show how to configure it in Remmina?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ubuntu are you on?
I managed to get it working on elementary Freya which is based on Ubuntu 14.04. I run remmina version 1.2.0-rcgit.4, and the gateway setting is under the domain setting. This picture shows it in Norwegian but I think you'll manage:
[remmina](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W017g.png)

Comment: On 17.04 the bundled version is still old. Installing through snap fixed it, and this version does have a gateway setting.